# How do you make use of local component's data object to bind to an external component

Tags: vue.js, vue-trix

how do you use a local component's data attriutes to bind an external component's `v-model`

for example i have this component

```
<publish-blog>
<VueTrix v-model="form.editorContent">
</publish-blog>
```

so the `form.editorContent` there refers to the `publish-blog` component's form.editorContent inside data, how do I do that ?

Comment: where is the other component located? do you use vuex? otherwise you can emit events either to a parent component, or use an event bus to share information between components....

Comment: You have taken a little too little sample code. Paste more, please

Comment: @Gander, there friend, what do you think of that ?

Comment: @TheBAST, If I understood correctly, you have data in PublishBlog you want to pass it as a bind to VueTrix? This looks like a place to use Renderless Components. Please read the article https://adamwathan.me/renderless-components-in-vuejs/